# Take User to Custom URL Using Form Data

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form which asks users for their first name, last name and a dropdown option - for example:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label for="searchText">Search:</label>
        <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" />
        <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" />
        <select>
        <option>All Records</option>
        <option value="wee">Option 1</option>
        <option value="er1">Option 2</option>
        <option value="rer">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

When a user completes this form I need them to be taken to a custom URL on a third party site using the data they submitted, the URL looks something like this:

https://www.example.com/?name=False&ViewType=Default&Step=1&secondname=0&option=0

My main issue is that the parameters I need to populate are between other parameters in the URL so doing something like the below is not possible:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var form = document.getElementById("form1");
        form.onsubmit = function(){
            var searchText = document.getElementById("searchText");
            window.location = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchText.value;
            return false;
        };          
    };
</script>
```

Comment: My answer might be wrong, because I am not sure what are you trying to do. Do you want to redirect people to example.com or to google search? Also, the 2 inputs have same name and the second one will overwrite the first one.

Comment: I need to redirect people to another domain (not Google) the problem is I can't just put the URL as the method, because there are other parameters already in the URL. I need to slot these parameters into the middle of the URL. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you can leave those parameters in the URL and the ones from the form will be added in at the end. Do you need them to be at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the method to GET (it will add the variables in the link automatically) and do action="www.example.com"